# How to execute bash script if a button is pressed in php?

Tags: php, bash

I think that it's a permissions problem, because in my script

there are some commands that need root privileges to execute

I added `www-data` to `sudoers` hoping it would solve the problem

and did

`exec("echo \"passwd\" | sudo -S ./myscript");`

in my php but it didn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You could use [shell_exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php).

```
shell_exec("echo \"passwd\" | sudo -S ./myscript");
```

But I'm not sure if it'll work with sudo.

Also I would like to say that adding www-data to sudoers is very dangerous.

Comment: sorry for the typo I meant `exec()` not 'echo()'... is there a difference regarding permissions with `shell_exec()`?

Comment: There is no difference. The question is why do you need the permissions? What are you trying to achieve? Because in most cases you can just change permissions for particular scripts, files, etc to solve the problem.

Comment: I'm trying to run a script that when I execute it from terminal as root (or with sudo) does something that it doesn't do when I call it from exec()... (not very clear I guess : ( I don't have access to the script at the moment)

Comment: maybe if I add sudo at the beginning of every command that needs root permissions in the script....?

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't help you. I don't know what your script does. "Talk is cheap. Show me the code." - Torvalds, Linus